# Add items to JSON object

Tags: javascript

I'm picking up a JSON object using a promise:

```
var x = get();
x.done(function(data) {
    for(var i in data) {

    }
});
```

which is returning this data when i do `console.log(data);`

```
[{…}]
0:
customer: "9028"
data:
active: "1"
customer: "9028"
description: ""
id: "13717"
inherited: "0"
name: "Out of Hours"
priority: "1"
shared: "0"
sound: ""
__proto__: Object
voip_seq: "4"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

so that is working fine, but within my for loop, I want to add 2 items to `data`

I tried adding this into my `.done`

```
var obj = { name: "Light" };
data.push(obj);
```

But that didn't add to `data`

My for loop looks like this:

```
                 for(var i in data) {
                    var m = '<option value="' + data[i].data.id + '"'
                    if(data[i].data.id == selected_val) {
                        m += ' selected="selected"';
                    }
                    m += '>' + data[i].data.name + '</option>';
                    $('#' + value_element_id).append(m);
                }
```

Comment: Do you mean a `javascript object`?  JSON = string, so "JSON object" = "string object".  In your `.done` the server is sending a JSON (string) which jquery is converting to a javascript object (`data`).

Comment: I could be wrong, but I'm pretty sure that `data` object is not a JS object. You would likely be better off creating a new object, mapping `data` onto it, and then adding your new values.

Comment: see my update with whats inside the for loop - apologies if im getting confused - my js/jquery knowledge isnt great

Comment: "that didn't add to data" ...not sure how that's possible: https://jsfiddle.net/d3q6h5Ln/1/. Might be wise to show us _exactly_ what you did. It's worth noting that `{ name: "Light" }` won't produce an object with the same structure as the one which is already in your `data` array, so it doesn't make a lot of sense to add such a thing. If you added that before you ran your loop, then the loop would likely crash when it got to that object, because of undefined properties in the object.

Comment: yes it's possible to omit the other fields, but at minimum you need to add an object which contains the structure and fields required by the loop. e.g. `{ "data": { "name": "light", "id": 1234 } }`. (Technically, this makes the other fields `undefined` rather than `null`, but for this purpose it won't make any difference.)

Comment: you mean you want to append to the inner `data` property _within_ the array item? Confusingly, there are two things called `data` in your code - a variable which is an array, and a property of an object within that array.

Comment: yeah, i want to add to the inner `data`

Comment: Yes of course. But the inner data is an object, not an array, so what exactly do you want to add to it? Your for loop to create the options is looping over the outer one, so I'm not clear what you would achieve by adding properties to the inner one. That code would not read them

Comment: the original function that returns `data` is being produced dynamically using an Ajax call. but on this one occasian, I want to add 2 additional options

Comment: Yes but my point was that adding it to the inner `data` isn't the right place. Can you see why? Your code is set up to expect it in the outer one. Demo of your code without adding extra items: https://jsfiddle.net/a286b7fw/. And with extra items:https://jsfiddle.net/a286b7fw/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add two more items to your select, you simply need to push new objects into your `data` array before your loop starts. The objects must contain the structure and properties ("name" and "id" within a "data" sub-property) matching the JSON coming from the Promise, so that your loop code can process them.

In the simplest case, it could be as straightforward as

```
x.done(function(data) {
  data.push({ "data": { "name": "light", "id": 1234 } });
  data.push({ "data": { "name": "dark", "id": 5678 } });

  for(var i in data) {
    var m = '<option value="' + data[i].data.id + '"'
    if (data[i].data.id == selected_val) {
      m += ' selected="selected"';
    }
    m += '>' + data[i].data.name + '</option>';
    $('#' + value_element_id).append(m);
  }
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/a286b7fw/1/

Answer (score -1):

In this case I think `data` is not an array so it hasn't `.push()` method. You can add property to object like this:

```
for(var i in data) {
  var m = '<option value="' + data[i].data.id + '"'
  if(data[i].data.id == selected_val) {
    m += ' selected="selected"';
  }
  m += '>' + data[i].data.name + '</option>';
  $('#' + value_element_id).append(m);

  // here it will add obj to data
  var obj = {name: "Light"};
  data = {
    ...data,
    obj
  }
}
```

Comment: see comment above :)

Comment: After for loop `data` will contain `obj` object. But loop wont iterate over  added properties.

Comment: @MeruzhJanoyan it makes no obvious sense to add a new object while the loop is already running. Not sure what the purpose of this code is intended to be? And `data` **is** an array. The output from the console.log makes that clear (output looks like it's from Chrome, and the `[{…}]` and `length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)` are very clear giveaways...what do you think the word "Array" is doing there?)

Comment: Anyway it is some mixed version of array and JSON object, so if he needed to add property into there he can do it using ES6 spread. @ADyson

Comment: " it is some mixed version of array and JSON object" ..., no it's not. What's your evidence for that exactly? There are no JSON strings in that console log. It's an **array**, and as such, items can be added using .push(). Here's the code which would produce that console.log output: https://jsfiddle.net/6cvt1rbm/